# Making MyView visible causes the RelativeLayout to shift downwards

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a smaller RelativeLayout and a custom layout  MyView which are both contained in a parent RelativeLayout. MyView is larger in size than the child RelativeLayout but only appears during a certain event. I don't want it to take up layout space outside of this event. However, when I set it to View.VISIBLE, it causes the child RelativeLayout to jump downwards.

The parent RelativeLayout which contains these views is to be moved around the screen. The parent view is moved when the user touches the screen and a MotionEvent.MOVE is triggered. When you move the parent view to the edges of the screen and the MyView is View.INVISIBLE, the problem is that the MyView will still take up space and have collision with the screen borders, and it looks like there is an invisible wall between the child RelativeLayout and the edge of the screen. I want the effective size of the whole parent RelativeLayout view to be the same as the child RelativeLayout unless the MyView is visible.

Here is an image to help illustrate my problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwH3R.jpg

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myapp">

<com.example.MyView
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="175dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/red"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" //Less than 175dp
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" //Less than 175dp
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

</RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

The merge view is then placed in a parent RelativeLayout which is defined in Java with these parameters.

```
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = (int) (deviceRes.y * 0.1);
```

Comment: Didn't quite understand the problem. So after making MyView visible, child RelativeLayout AND this MyView layout jump downwards? Or only child RelativeLayout? And what do you mean by "effective size of the whole view"?

Comment: "So after making MyView visible, child RelativeLayout AND this MyView layout jump downwards?" : Yes, "effective size of the whole view"? : The parent view that holds all of these child views should be the same size of the child RelativeLayout when MyView is not visible/gone, but when MyView is View.INVISIBLE, it still collides with the screen. Edited the original to help explain it.

Comment: Please explain collision/collides. Are you monitoring when parts of MyView leave the screen?

Comment: Edited to explain collision. I'm not monitoring when MyView (partially) leaves the screen. In fact it doesn't seem able to leave the screen at all when I move the parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by pulling the MyView out of the merge view. I just made it so the MyView follows the movement of the merge view. So now the MyView and merge view are children of the screen manager and MyView is not a child of the merge view.

Answer (score 1):

Change the visibility to `invisible` instead of `gone.

`Invisible` still takes up the space so your layout won't move.

`gone` frees up that space. So, when you make it visible again, of course everything will shift.

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility)

> Constant    Value   Description
>
> visible    0   Visible on screen; the default value.
>
> invisible  1   Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it).
>
> gone   2   Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.

Comment: The problem is that the MyView will still have collision with the screen borders. I want the effective size of the whole view to be the same as the child RelativeLayout unless the MyView is visible.

I've edited the original problem statement to reflect this.

Comment: You have `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in both so yes that's going to put it in the same position. Where do you want this `View`, at the top of the screen?

Comment: Well in the picture, I basically want the child RelativeLayout to retain the same (x,y) coordinates it used to have when the MyView was set to View.GONE.

Comment: Right, but where do you want `MyView`? Above that child? Right now you are placing it where the child is so of course it's going to move it

Comment: I want the MyView to be centered behind the child when visible.

Answer (score 0):

Check your relative layout in the design view of Android Studio.

Is any of your child view's distance referenced from outside the parent layout?

If so, then better to add constraints of that child's views with some reference inside the relative layout